# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

No logro mostrar los datos que me trae la consulta. trabajo con mySQL y un modelo de vistas y controladores.

Me sale este error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in

Y la variable no esta vacía.

```
public function listaTarjetas(){
    $db=BaseDeDatos::conectarBD();

    $sql='select * from tarjetas;';

    $result=mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    return $result;
}
    
$usuario = new Model_Usuario();

$tarjetas =  $usuario->listaTarjetas();


<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($data)>0){
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
        echo $rows['idTarjetas'];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un pequeño error al pasar el parámetro a la función `mysqli_num_rows` que espera un objeto como resultado de la query.

```
$tarjetas =  $usuario->listaTarjetas();
if(mysqli_num_rows($data)>0){ <----- aquí deberías pasar la variable $tarjetas
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){ <----- aquí también
        echo $rows['idTarjetas'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Las lineas de código están desarrolladas en distintas vistas. la variable $data la uso para tomar los valores que le paso por parámetro desde el controlador hacia la vista. el data es una variable predeterminada para tomar los result  de las consultas.

Comment: En ese caso recomendaría que coloques un ejemplo que se pueda rutear sin hacer mayores preguntas al respecto, dado que como está planteado el ejemplo no queda claro el cómo está configurado tu ambiente. Si deseas ayuda, ayúdanos a ayudarte https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask